# How to achieve URL structure like "website-name/archive-page/category(or custom taxonomy)/custom-post-type" in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, custom-post-type, categories

So, I've been trying to make a page that looks like this:

If I go to 'website-name/tutorials' I get the list of my tutorial serie names (only names, not specific tutorials). I made a custom post type named "tutorial" and set it's URL to "tutorials", so this URL is plural.

However, no matter if I use custom taxonomies or categories, I can't get the URL structure I want, which is explained below:

If the user goes to 'website-name/tutorials' and clicks on one of the tutorial series, he gets to the URL of 'website-name/tutorials/tutorial-serie-name'. Then, he gets the list of all of the tutorials belonging to that custom taxonomy/category (because I tried using both custom taxonomies and categories) and gets to the URL 'website-name/tutorials/tutorial-serie-name/specific-tutorial-name'.

As I have stated, I tried using custom taxonomies and categories, but I simply can't make this URL structure, it is always 'website-name/tutorials/specific-tutorial-name' or, when I made category.php it was (note : category-name was the same as my tutorial serie name) : 'website-name/category/category-name'.

I just can't get that URL structure. I don't know how to achieve this, nor do I know do I have to use custom taxonomies in order to achieve it or I can stick to categories?

P.S. If you're wondering why I have to have this URL structure, it's because some of my tutorial series have tutorials with same name in them. For example, in my JavaScript series I have a tutorial named "Installing the program" and also in my C++ tutorial series I have that same tutorial name. So that's why I need this URL structure.

Comment: have you tried using %category% in the permalink settings?

Comment: I have not. Care to elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

go to your permalink settings and use %category% in the custom options something like `/%category%/%postname%` should make it so that your category names appear in the permalink structure... 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.25category.25_with_multiple_categories_on_a_post

Comment: That's great, but, how do I make them go 'website-name/tutorials/category/postname', not just 'website-name/category/postname'?

Comment: depends on how you have it set up:

Comment: I've changed it from admin panel, it looks like this now : http://localhost/final/%category%/%postname% EDIT : When I visit 'localhost/final/category-name/post-name' I get this 'localhost/final/tutorials/post-name'... it omits the category-name in between the tutorials and post name.

Comment: and your sure it's using category and not taxonomy?

Comment: have you tried this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-custom-permalink-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy?replies=17

Comment: Yes... I'm not using any custom taxonomy. I just tried making the same post name in another category, and WP defaulted the URL to 'localhost/final/tutorials/post-name-2'. Notice the "2". And that's the exact reason why I would like to rewrite it this way.

Comment: Just to give you an update, I made a category of "Tutorials" and set it to be the parent of my other tutorial categories, but no luck... I'll test this plugin out. At least now I know that I should use categories instead of custom taxonomies for this kind of thing.

Comment: good luck mate if you want to pop on the wordpress IRC I'm on there to lend a hand

Comment: Nope, the plugin doesn't work. I get no content either on 'localhost/final/tutorials/post-name' or 'localhost/final/tutorials/category-name/post-name'.